# SPSS vs R, Why fitted values of SMA are different?

Tags: r, time-series, spss, moving-average

In SPSS, fitted value of SMA(**order=4**) as follows:

```
 Yt     Year Quarter  Date   Y_fit
98.7    2004    1   Q1 2004 
98.6    2004    2   Q2 2004 
100.6   2004    3   Q3 2004 
99.5    2004    4   Q4 2004 
100.1   2005    1   Q1 2005  99.35
98.9    2005    2   Q2 2005  99.70
101.0   2005    3   Q3 2005  99.78
100.0   2005    4   Q4 2005  99.88
99.6    2006    1   Q1 2006  100.00
98.7    2006    2   Q2 2006  99.88
101.1   2006    3   Q3 2006  99.83
100.1   2006    4   Q4 2006  99.85
101.0   2007    1   Q1 2007  99.88
100.6   2007    2   Q2 2007  100.23
103.2   2007    3   Q3 2007  100.70
102.8   2007    4   Q4 2007  101.23
102.9   2008    1   Q1 2008  101.90
104.4   2008    2   Q2 2008  102.38
106.1   2008    3   Q3 2008  103.32
105.5   2008    4   Q4 2008  104.05
```

In R, fitted value of SMA(**order=4**) as follows:

```
gdp=ts(data$Yt, frequency=4, start=c(2004,1))
SMA(gdp, n=4)
         Qtr1    Qtr2    Qtr3    Qtr4
 2004      NA      NA      NA  99.350
 2005  99.700  99.775  99.875 100.000
 2006  99.875  99.825  99.850  99.875
 2007 100.225 100.700 101.225 101.900
 2008 102.375 103.325 104.050 104.725
```

I mean, **why the number of NA is different?** The values of R is pulled by one space.

If I enter that the order is 5 in R, the number of NA is 4 like SPSS. However the fitted values are different from values of SPSS.

I know the moving average.. that if order is 4,(t1+t2+t3+t4/4) is **t5**.
But in R it seems to be (t1+t2+t3+t4/4)=**t4**.

Also, cma(**data, n=4**) in R, the result don't have NA. But the result of SPSS have 4 NA(2 in the front, 2 in the back).

1. Result of SPSS, cma(data, n=4). Y_fit2 is fitted values.

   ```
   Yt     Year Quarter  Date    Y_fit1  Y_fit2
   98.7     2004    1   Q1 2004         
   98.6     2004    2   Q2 2004     
   100.6    2004    3   Q3 2004          99.52
   99.5     2004    4   Q4 2004          99.74
   100.1    2005    1   Q1 2005  99.35   99.83
   98.9     2005    2   Q2 2005  99.70   99.94
   101.0    2005    3   Q3 2005  99.78   99.94
   100.0    2005    4   Q4 2005  99.88   99.85
   99.6     2006    1   Q1 2006  100.00  99.84
   98.7     2006    2   Q2 2006  99.88   99.86
   101.1    2006    3   Q3 2006  99.83   100.05
   100.1    2006    4   Q4 2006  99.85   100.46
   101.0    2007    1   Q1 2007  99.88   100.96
   100.6    2007    2   Q2 2007  100.23  101.56
   103.2    2007    3   Q3 2007  100.70  102.14
   102.8    2007    4   Q4 2007  101.23  102.85
   102.9    2008    1   Q1 2008  101.90  103.69
   104.4    2008    2   Q2 2008  102.38  104.39
   106.1    2008    3   Q3 2008  103.32 
   105.5    2008    4   Q4 2008  104.05
   ```
2. Result of R, cma(data, n=4)

   ```
   cma(gdp, order=4)$fitted
              Qtr1      Qtr2      Qtr3      Qtr4
      2004  99.11958  99.20039  99.35312  99.52500
      2005  99.73750  99.82500  99.93750  99.93750
      2006  99.85000  99.83750  99.86250 100.05000
      2007 100.46250 100.96250 101.56250 102.13750
      2008 102.85000 103.68750 104.38750 104.91094
   ```

So, can we say that the result of SPSS and the result of R are the same?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, `TTR::SMA(AirPassengers, n = 5)` is giving me 4 `NA`'s.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was typing mistake. I entered "SMA(data, n=4)". Because the order was entered "4" in SPSS. However, the results of SPSS and R are different.